# Como Inserir na pilha de dados uma string

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Eu preciso fazer uma pilha que faça um push, pop e impressão. Então eu criei as funções e isso funciona. Mas eu queria adicionar uma String à minha pilha. Possivelmente um número e hora ou apenas uma string. Mas eu não consigo nenhum dos dois. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5  

struct pilha
{
    int pilhaa[MAXSIZE];
    int top;

};

typedef struct pilha PILHA;
PILHA p;

void push(void);
int  pop(void);
void display(void);

void main ()
{
    int escolha;
    int opcao = 1;
    p.top = -1;

    printf ("Operacoes da Pilha\n");
    while (opcao)
    {
        printf ("------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("      1    -->    PUSH               \n");
        printf ("      2    -->    POP               \n");
        printf ("      3    -->    DISPLAY               \n");
        printf ("      4    -->    EXIT                   \n");
        printf ("------------------------------------------\n");

        printf ("Escolha uma opcao!\n");
        scanf    ("%d", &escolha);
        switch (escolha)
        {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            display();
            break;
        case 4:
            return;
        }
        fflush (stdin);
        printf ("(Digite 0 para 'SAIR' ou 1 para 'CONTINUAR')?\n");
        scanf    ("%d", &opcao);
    }
}
/* Função para adicionar um elemento à pilha */
void push()
{
    char value[20];

    if (p.top == (MAXSIZE - 1))
    {
        printf ("Pilha Cheia!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Digite o numero no formato INTEIRO \n");
        scanf ("%s", value);


        p.top = p.top + 1;
        p.pilhaa[p.top] = value;
    }
    return;
}
/* Função para excluir um elemento da pilha */
int pop()
{
    int num;
    if (p.top == - 1)
    {
        printf ("Pilha Vazia!\n");
        return (p.top);
    }
    else
    {
        num = p.pilhaa[p.top];
        printf ("Elemento a ser retirado eh: = %d\n", p.pilhaa[p.top]);
        p.top = p.top - 1;
    }
    return(num);
}
/* Função para exibir o status da pilha */
void display()
{
    int i;
    if (p.top == -1)
    {
        printf ("Pilha Vazia\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Os status da pilha é: \n");
        for (i = p.top; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf ("%s", p.pilhaa[i]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: Mas a pilha é suposto ter strings ou numeros ? Parece que numas situações está a tentar usar um e noutras outro

Comment: A principio fiz usando inteiro. Depois alterei só o empilhar(push) pra string.. Mas deu pau e postei aqui pra ver se alguém me dá uma luz.

Comment: Mas é para ficar com números ou strings ? Com números é mais fácil

Comment: Em C se você declara um array de um tipo, não poderá armazenar outro tipo no array. Existem algumas formas de contornar isso, uma delas seria ter um array do tipo void* MAS isso NÃO é uma boa prática e pode dar muita dor de cabeça. Você gostaria de ter uma pilha apenas de strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STACK_MAXSIZE 5
#define STRING_MAXSIZE 10

struct pilha
{
    char pilhaa[STACK_MAXSIZE][STRING_MAXSIZE];
    int top;

};

typedef struct pilha PILHA;
PILHA p;

void push(void);
void  pop(void);
void display(void);

int main ()
{
    int escolha;
    int opcao = 1;
    p.top = -1;

    printf ("Operacoes da Pilha\n");
    while (opcao)
    {
        printf ("------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("      1    -->    PUSH               \n");
        printf ("      2    -->    POP               \n");
        printf ("      3    -->    DISPLAY               \n");
        printf ("      4    -->    EXIT                   \n");
        printf ("------------------------------------------\n");

        printf ("Escolha uma opcao!\n");
        scanf    ("%d", &escolha);
        switch (escolha)
        {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            display();
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        }
        fflush (stdin);
        printf ("(Digite 0 para 'SAIR' ou 1 para 'CONTINUAR')?\n");
        scanf    ("%d", &opcao);
    }

    return 0;
}
/* Função para adicionar um elemento à pilha */
void push()
{
    char value[STRING_MAXSIZE];

    if (p.top == (STACK_MAXSIZE - 1))
    {
        printf ("Pilha Cheia!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Digite a string \n");
        scanf ("%s", value);

        p.top = p.top + 1;

        for (int i=0; i<STRING_MAXSIZE; i++) {
          p.pilhaa[p.top][i] = value[i];

          if(value[i] == '\0') break;
        }
    }
} 
/* Função para excluir um elemento da pilha */
void pop()
{
    char num[STRING_MAXSIZE];
    if (p.top == - 1)
    {
        printf ("Pilha Vazia!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Elemento a ser retirado eh: = %s\n", p.pilhaa[p.top]);
        p.top = p.top - 1;
    }
}
/* Função para exibir o status da pilha */
void display()
{
    int i;
    if (p.top == -1)
    {
        printf ("Pilha Vazia\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Os status da pilha é: \n");
        for (i = p.top; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            printf ("%s\n", p.pilhaa[i]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse exemplo cria uma pilha com strings, sem usar alocação dinâmica, coloca algusn valores na pilha e depois retira e coloca todos em uma outra

#### saída do exemplo

```
Teste: ainda vazia
Pilha VAZIA (cap:10):

Teste: primeira pilha
5 elementos (cap:10):
        Verde
        Vermelho
        Marrom
        Cinza
        Branco


Tirando os elementos e colocando na outra pilha:


Ao final: pilha original
Pilha VAZIA (cap:10):

Ao final: pilha resultante
5 elementos (cap:10):
        Branco
        Cinza
        Marrom
        Vermelho
        Verde
```

#### O código C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO_ 10
#define LIMITE_ 40

typedef char Registro;

typedef struct
{
    int  tam; // quantos tem
    int  lim; // quantos cabem
    char dado[LIMITE_][TAMANHO_];

} Pilha;

int POP(Pilha*);
int PUSH(const char*, Pilha*);
int TOP(Pilha*, char*);

int mostra(Pilha*, const char*);
Pilha* cria(size_t limite);
Pilha* destroi(Pilha* pilha);


int main(void)
{
    const char* teste[] = {
        "Verde", "Vermelho", "Marrom", "Cinza", "Branco"};
    Pilha orig = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: ainda vazia");
    int res   = 0;
    int n_tst = sizeof(teste) / sizeof(teste[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_tst; i += 1)
    {
        res = PUSH((const char*)teste[i], &orig);
        if (res < 1) break;
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nTeste: primeira pilha");
    // agora tira um por um e poe na outra pilha
    printf(
        "\nTirando os elementos e colocando na outra "
        "pilha:\n\n");
    Pilha reversa = {.tam = 0, .lim = TAMANHO_};
    char  el[LIMITE_];
    for (int i = orig.tam; i > 0; i -= 1)
    {
        TOP(&orig, el);
        POP(&orig);
        PUSH(el, &reversa);
    }
    mostra(&orig, "\nAo final: pilha original");
    mostra(&reversa, "\nAo final: pilha resultante");
    return 0;
}

// tira um cara da pilha, retorna o tamanho
int POP(Pilha* p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return -1;
    if (p->tam == 0) return -2;
    p->tam -= 1;
    return p->tam;
}

// poe um cara na pilha, retorna o tamanho
int PUSH(const char* val, Pilha* p)
{
    if ((p == NULL) || (val == NULL)) return -1;
    if (strlen(val) > TAMANHO_ - 1) return -2;  // nao cabe
    p->tam += 1;
    if (p->tam > p->lim)
    {
        p->tam -= 1;
        return -3;
    }
    strcpy(p->dado[p->tam], val);
    return p->tam;
}

int TOP(Pilha* p, Registro* val)
{
    if ((p == NULL) || (val == NULL)) return -1;
    if (p->tam == 0) return -2;
    strcpy(val, p->dado[p->tam]);
    return 0;
}

int mostra(Pilha* p, const char* tit)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("pilha invalida\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    if (p->tam == 0)
    {
        printf("Pilha VAZIA (cap:%d):\n", p->lim);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d elementos (cap:%d):\n", p->tam, p->lim);
    for (int i = 1; i < p->tam; i += 1)
        printf("\t%s\n", p->dado[i]);
    printf("\t%s\n\n", p->dado[p->tam]);
    return 0;
}

Pilha* cria(size_t limite)
{
    Pilha* nova = (Pilha*)malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if (nova == NULL) return NULL;
    nova->lim = (int) limite;
    nova->tam = 0; // marca como vazia
    return nova; // tudo certo: retorna a pilha nova
}

Pilha* destroi(Pilha* pilha)
{
    if (pilha == NULL) return NULL;
    free(pilha->dado);
    free(pilha);
    return NULL;
}
```